# Ajax não funciona no Firefox

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Funciona perfeitamente no navegador Chrome, e nos outros navegadores não...

Quando eu digito o login e senha ele exibe a mensagem "Login Efetuado com Sucesso!" e fica parada a página no Mozilla.

Veja o código:

```php
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"1;URL=inicio.php\" />";
echo "Login Efetuado com Sucesso!";

$(function() {
    caminho = $('.logar');
    action = 'ajax/php/logar.php';
    enviar = $('form[name="logar"]');

    function resposta(datas) {
        caminho.html(datas);
    }

    enviar.submit(function() {
        var cadastrar = $.post(action, $(this).serialize());
        cadastrar.progress(resposta('<center><i class="icon-spin1 animate-spin"></i>Carregando...</center>'));
        cadastrar.done(resposta);
        cadastrar.fail(function() {
            resposta('Erro ao Cadastrar');
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Creio que você quis se referir ao Firefox, uma vez que Mozilla é apenas a organização que mantém o Firefox. Qual é a versão do Firefox? Qual é a versão do jQuery? Como é que é o seu formulário? Aparece alguma coisa no console do navegador? Funciona no IE?

Comment: @Victor isso é que é perguntar :D

Comment: Aparece algum erro no console do javascript/firebug?

Answer (score 2):

O problema não é que a requisição não esteja funcionando, é a forma com que você está tentando redirecionar o usuário. Provavelmente o Chrome é o único que considera a `metatag` que você está usando após o carregamento da página.

Como solução, eu lhe indico a trocar o seu código de resposta por algo parecido com isso:

```
echo "<script>
         setTimeout(function() {
             window.location.href = 'inicio.php';
         }, 1000);
     </script>";

echo "Login Efetuado com Sucesso!";
```

Mas ainda assim, não gosto desta forma de colocar javascript no servidor. Embora seja de gosto de cada um, eu lhe recomendo a mudar a resposta do servidor, como por exemplo, retornar um objeto `JSON` e tratar a resposta no javascript. Segue exemplo:

```
// php
$resposta = array();
$resposta["loginEfetuado"] = true;
echo json_encode($resposta);

// js
function resposta(data) {
    if (data.loginEfetuado) {
        caminho.html("Login Efetuado com Sucesso!");
        setTimeout(function() {
            window.location.href = "inicio.php";
        }, 1000);
    } else {
        caminho.html("Falha ao tentar efetuar login!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo , resolvi com o seus dois exemplo :) não sabia que o metatag daria esse problema em outros navegadores Valew pela ajuda.